# Macro to Copy ONLY Formatting of Matched Value in Different Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

In advance, thank you for your help.
In Excel 2016, I have a workbook with 3 sheets labelled 9am, 12pm and 330pm.
I have columns A through AF with values and formats set for each row.
Right now, after some research on StackOverflow already, I have found a Macro that looks for values in column A in sheet 9am up to the last found value, then copies that value with it's cell formatting, as well as the values of the rest of the row cells (up to column AF), into the 12pm sheet.
Code shown below:

```
Private Sub CopyDataAndFormat12pm()
Dim NewDataRng As Range 'For 12pm
Dim cel As Range 'For 12pm
Dim OldDataRng As Range 'For 9am
Dim MatchingValueCell As Range 'For 9am
Dim lastrow As Long

With Sheets("9am")
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set NewDataRng = .Range("A2:A" & CStr(lastrow))
End With

With Sheets("12pm")
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OldDataRng = .Range("A2:A" & CStr(lastrow))
End With

For Each cel In NewDataRng
    Set MatchingValueCell = OldDataRng.Find(What:=cel.Value, _
    After:=OldDataRng.Cells(OldDataRng.Cells.Count))
    If Not MatchingValueCell Is Nothing Then _
    cel.Resize(1, 8).Copy MatchingValueCell

Next cel
End sub
```

This works great, except that I also have a macro that pastes the newest list of values for our 12pm report and automatically formats it for me, and the 12pm sheet may have new values for some of the columns (specifically columns C, I, J and K) and I need to retain the new values.
So basically, I need to modify this code so that it only pastes the formatting of rows (for columns A:AF for each row) into the new 12pm sheet for the matching values it finds.
I have tried modifying the code to:

```
    For Each cel In NewDataRng
    Set MatchingValueCell = OldDataRng.Find(What:=cel.Value, _
    After:=OldDataRng.Cells(OldDataRng.Cells.Count))
    If Not MatchingValueCell Is Nothing Then _
    cel.Copy
    cel.Resize(1, 31).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

But when I run it, it flashes the screen like crazy as it runs the code, and looks like it's doing what I want, but when the code finishes compiling, nothing is saved and it looks like the code never ran.

Sorry if this isn't a good explanation, and if you need more code, please ask and I'll be more than happy to provide it as soon as possible.

Thank you so much if you can help me!

Regards,
Brady

Comment: I need to review your description more closely, but for the "flashes the screen like crazy" part, you can use `Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE` at the beginning of your sub and `Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE` at the end of it.

Comment: In your second code snippet, `cel.copy` is only copying from one cell in column A from the 9 AM worksheet. You are pasting the format of that cell into row stretching from A to AF in the 9 AM worksheet. I think you are wanting to copy from A to AF in the 9 am sheet and paste formats into A to AF in the 12 PM worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for your input so far!
I added the ScreenUpdating code to my modules.
Also, you are correct that I am wanting to copy the A:AF cell formats of each row with the matching value in cell A#, and pasting only the format to the 12pm sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't any data to test this against, but try something like the following ...

```
For Each cel In NewDataRng
    Set MatchingValueCell = OldDataRng.Find(What:=cel.Value, _
    After:=OldDataRng.Cells(OldDataRng.Cells.Count))
    If Not MatchingValueCell Is Nothing Then _
    Sheets("9am").Rows(MatchingValueCell.Row).Copy
    Sheets("12pm").Rows(cel.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Next cel
```

Comment: I tested that modification, and while I got really excited that it looked to work, it didn't.
I ended up with fill formatting where some didn't match the values of the A column cells, and some did on the 12pm sheet.